# What operating system etcd uses

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I logged into Kubernetes etcd pod

```
kubectl exec -it -n kube-system etcd-master -- /bin/sh
```

I cannot figure out what OS is it.

ls does not work

```
sh-5.0# ls
sh: ls: command not found
```

cat does not work

```
sh-5.0# cat /etc/os-release
sh: cat: command not found
```

apt,yum not recognized

```
sh-5.0# apt
sh: apt: command not found

sh-5.0# yum
sh: yum: command not found
```

I can only cd and list files via pattern expansion

```
sh-5.0# cd /etc
sh-5.0# echo *
debian_version default dpkg group host.conf hostname hosts issue issue.net kubernetes network nsswitch.conf os-release passwd profile.d protocols resolv.conf rpc services skel ssl update-motd.d

sh-5.0# echo `<os-release`
PRETTY_NAME="Distroless" NAME="Debian GNU/Linux" ID="debian" VERSION_ID="9" VERSION="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)" HOME_URL="https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless" SUPPORT_URL="https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/README.md" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/issues/new"
```

What operating system is it? How to install bash here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/etc/os-release` states that the image is based on `Distroless`. The [SUPPORT_URL](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/master/README.md) given there explains that:

> "Distroless" images contain only your application and its runtime dependencies.
> They do not contain package managers, shells or any other programs you would expect to find in a standard Linux distribution.
>
> For more information, see this [talk](https://swampup2017.sched.com/event/A6CW/distroless-docker-containerizing-apps-not-vms?iframe=no&w=100%&sidebar=yes&bg=no) ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lviLZFciDv4)).

This is one of the best practices with containers to leave only what is absolutely necessary inside. You may encounter many such images and some even won't have `sh` in it. Moreover, root filesystem can be read only and/or the container might not have enough privileges to install things.

With all this in mind, it may be so that you will not be able to bring `bash` or anything else inside. Depending on your actual goal, you may:

1. Try to copy files out of the container with `kubectl cp` (requires `tar` inside the image);
2. Get into the host node of the container and locate container files on the host. You may as well use `docker cp` on the host to push `bash` binary inside the running container.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by `PRETTY_NAME`, it's Distroless (https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless). On their README, you can read

> Who uses Distroless?
>
> - Kubernetes, since v1.15
> - ...

Which is probably your case.